# Enforcing a full address user input

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my website, I allow members to use the Google Maps integration I have in order to search and select their home address.

I'm trying to figure out a way in which I could enforce a full address selection only.

At the moment, the member sees a search box and a map, once he inputs a search the result is shown on the map and he can choose 'This is my address'.

My current issue is that a lot of people selects 'Fairfax, USA' for example, rather than the exact address.

I know this is a lot about disciplining the members, but is there any technical way of preventing them from choosing a 'too general' address?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked much with the google maps api, but you can send their input to the [web service api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html), and load the first given result, and ask if that's their address, and only accept addresses from the api...

Edit: (Based on our talk in the comments)
When you ask the api to find an address it tells you what kind of location it returns for you, just simply check for "type" "street_address" on line four of your result like in [this api request](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA&sensor=false).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I can communicate with google maps, validate the address and display the location. However I'm having trouble differentiating between a general address as 'Fairfax, USA' to a specific 'household' address.

Comment: Okay, when you send a request google tells you the type of address you get, like in this example you can see that fourth line says " "types": [ "street_address" ], " http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false I hope it helps. :)

Comment: @Kristoffer la Cour - wow, that really helps, I'll look into it to see if it really doesn't give any false positives. Thanks!

Comment: You should check that all required address components exist in Google's geocoder result. However, note that some addresses may not have all such components such as a street name or number, especially if it's not in the US (and even for some places in the US, I think).

Comment: @Archimedix - can you give such an example? Thanks

Comment: @Kristoffer la Cour - can you please update your answer to include what you wrote in your comment? I would like to accept it.